# How to add content into php loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-lists

I have a 'ul' which contains a php loop. Now I need to dynamically add content into the loop from javascript. I've successfully used `jQuery .each()` to add the content into each 'li'. But there is something wrong with the result.

Here's my code:

```
<ul id="ulID">
    <?php
    if(isset($nav_data['all_notifications'])) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $nav_data['number_of_notes'] && $i < 4; $i++){
        ?>
        <li>
            <p id="content">
                <?php echo $nav_data['all_notifications'][$i]['other_fullname'];?>

                //I need to add the content here
            </p>
        </li>

        <script>
        var notiTime = moment("<?php echo $nav_data['all_notifications'][$i]['time_sent']?>").format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");

        $('#ulID li p').each(function(i) { 
            (this).append(notiTime);
        });
        </script>
</ul>
```

In the output, the first li contains all 4 contents. The second list contains 3 contents. The third list contain 2 contents, and the last list contain the last content.

I think there's a mistake with how the script appends the content into the loop list. But I'm not sure how to change it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: is your `<script>` tag inside your php `for loop`?

Comment: @EhsanT Yes. It is inside the loop.

Comment: So, move it outside of the loop! And it will solve your problem.

Comment: @EhsanT If I move it out, it will not loop through the data list.

Comment: Actually it should, because of `.each()`

Comment: Right now you have your `<script>` in your loop and in each loop of `php for` you will have one loop of `javascript`, if first `php loop` you have one `<li>` so your `javascript` loop will run once. in your second loop of `php for` you will have 2 `<li>` so your `javascript` loop will run twice and so on... So you have to move yout `<script>` out of your `php for` loop and it will only run once and loop through all of your `<li>` tags only one time...

Comment: In the first php loop, I get 4 data. In the second, I get 3, the thrid I get 2, the forth I get1. When I put the script out of the for loop, every list will get only one data. However, that one data is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131990/discussion-between-ehsant-and-woshinibaba).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's break your code down.

You have a `for` loop which generates 4 `<li>` tags:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $nav_data['number_of_notes'] && $i < 4; $i++){
```

Now you have a `<script>` inside your `for` loop. Inside this `<script>` you have another loop `.each()`.

So when you are in the first `php` loop, you have only 1 `<li>` and the JavaScript loop finds that 1 `<li>` and appends the `notiTime` variable to it.

In the second `php` loop, you have 2 `<li>`s and then your `<script>` runs again and this time, your JavaScript finds them and appends the new `notiTime` variable to them (now for the first `<li>`, we will have two contents of `notiTime` variable).

And this goes for the third and fourth `php` loops as well...

**The solution:**

In your JavaScript code, instead of looping through `<li>` tags, each time we will find only the last-child of `<ul>` which will be the latest `<li>` created (using `:last-child` selector) and only append the `notiTime` variable to it.

So I won't touch any part of your code except the `<script>` part and it will be like this:

```
<script> 
  var notiTime = moment("<?php echo $nav_data['all_notifications'][$i]['time_sent']?>").format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"); 
  $( "#ulID li:last-child p" ).append(notiTime); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <ul id="ulID">
       <?php if(isset($nav_data['all_notifications'])) {
          for($i = 0; $i < $nav_data['number_of_notes'] && $i < 4; $i++){
       ?>
          <li>
             <p id="content">
              <?php echo $nav_data['all_notifications'][$i]['other_fullname'];?>

                //I need to add the content here

             </p>
          </li>
    <?php } ?>
    <script>
    var notiTime = moment("<?php echo $nav_data['all_notifications'][$i]['time_sent']?>").format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");

             $('#ulID li p').each(function(i) { 
                   (this).append(notiTime);
    });
    </script>
    </ul>
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: Hii there is two mistakes first you havn't closed for loop second one not havnt closed each function too.. I updated that code please check it now

Comment: Hey I'm sorry that I made a mistake when I copied the code. But this is still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131945/discussion-between-nishant-saini-and-woshinibaba).

Answer (score -1):

PHP scripts render pages on the server.  JS runs on the client.  By the time the JS has a chance to execute, the page has already been rendered and serverd

Comment: The script can still change the format of the date/time data loaded through php, and then display the new format in the webpage. So I suppose that I should use php to change the date/time format directly. Thanks for answering.